# SharePoint Applications pools are crashed

Tags: sharepoint-server

The security token application pools are frequently getting crashed. From the uls logs,

> 07/13/2017 12:28:39.72
>   w3wp.exe (0x2470)   0x2A40  SharePoint Foundation   General avey    High
>   The application domain /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/SecurityTokenServiceApplication-1-131439220301668525 is unloading and going to be recycled.

What could be the possible reasons and how to prevent it?

Comment: Which SP environment are you working ?

Comment: Check the System Event log for the error

Comment: environment is 2013 and i found nothing from event viewer logs.

Answer (score 3):

If SharePoint Application Pools are stopped that would cause "Service Unavailable" outages to your SharePoint environment! While SCOM can monitor SharePoint IIS web application's application pool status, it makes bit more noisy with alerts and doesn't start the application pool automatically - when stopped. So, lets address this issue with the help of PowerShell! Here is my nifty PowerShell script to monitor application pools on all SharePoint web front end servers.

This script not only scans IIS Application Pool status on SharePoint Web-Front end servers, But also:

A- Logs application Pool status if its not in Started state

B- Automatically starts AppPool if its in stopped state

C- Sends out an Alert-Email to SharePoint Admin team (or whoever configured!)

```
PowerShell script to Monitor IIS Application Pool statues:

#Array to hold Server names - Change it to YOUR SharePoint front end servers
$WFEServers =("HS-WFE01", "HS-WFE02", "HS-WFE03")

#Log file location
$LogFile = "D:\Scripts\AppPool-Log.txt"

#Loop through each server and Check Application Pool status
foreach ($Server in $WFEServers)
{
$ServerMgr = [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote ($Server)

#Get all Application Pools which are not in Started State
$AppPoolColl = $ServerMgr.ApplicationPools | Where-Object {$_.State -ne "Started"}

foreach($AppPool in $AppPoolColl)
{
    #Get the time to Log
    $now = Get-Date –f "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    #Log to file
    "`n Found Application Pool: $($AppPool.name) in stopped state at the server : $($Server) on $($now)" >> $LogFile
    "Trying to Start the application Pool...">> $LogFile

    #Try Starting the application Pool
    $AppPool.Start()
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    "Application Pool's current Status: $($AppPool.State)" >> $LogFile

    #Send Alert-Mail message
    $emailFrom = "AppPoolMonitor@crescent.com"
    # Use commas for multiple addresses
    $emailTo = "SPAdmins@crescent.com"
    $subject = "Application Pool: $($AppPool.Name) in stopped state in Server: $($Server) at $($now)"
    $body = "Hi SharePoint Team, `n `n The Application Pool $($AppPool.name) was in stopped state in server: $($server). `n`n We tried Re-starting it... Current State of the Application Pool: $($AppPool.State). `n`n Please take necessary actions if its not started !. `n `nThanks, `nSharePoint AppPool Monitoring Script."
    $smtpServer = "<a class="vglnk" href="http://smtp.crescent.com" rel="nofollow"><span>smtp</span><span>.</span><span>crescent</span><span>.</span><span>com</span></a>" #IP or HOST Name of SMTP Server
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
}
}
```

Schedule this PowerShell script in Windows Task scheduler in any Application server (or any other server will do!) to periodically scan App Pool status, Say once per 5 Min! run interval can be adjusted based on your application priority.

Comment: This is a reactive measure which i kept it in place already. I want to understand what could be the reason for the crash and how to troubleshoot?