# Application Pools often crash

Tags: sharepoint-server

In our environment, application pools often crash. Atleast once in a week. On those applications, custom logic were build and also, there are very high threshold settings - 500000 items.

My threshold settings are the reason for app pools crash?

How could i understand the root cause of app pools crash?

Comment: Refer My answer that I gave the same question :                                                                                                       https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220712/sharepoint-applications-pools-are-crashed/220721#220721

Answer (score 0):

it is not easy thing to troubleshoot the app pool crashing issues, lets start with basic.

- Check the System Event log and look for WAS error.this will give you a clue why it is recycling the app pool.
- You mentioned that you have some custom code in the farm, i would remove that code from farm and check if the app pool crashed issues go away.
- Test your custom logic in the dev farm to test it.
- Check the traffic on the server
- May be you need Diag tool to get the dumps when app pool crashed to examine the error.

Check this [link for information](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2fddbf6a-2e42-487b-8f66-779bed695a6c/sharepoint-app-pool-keeps-stop?forum=sharepointadminprevious)